# how to change the value of one column based on another column value in Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a huge Dataframe that I'm reading using Dask dataFrame.
In pandas I use,

```
df.loc[df['Ref']!='ABC','Ref2'] = np.nan
```

Then I frontfill the changed column as shown below,

```
df['Ref2'] = df['Ref2'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

for making a change in a column based on condition on another column value.

How can the same be achieved using Dask Dataframe?

I'm new to Dask Dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dask.dataframe.Series.mask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.mask.html) and [`dask.dataframe.Series.fillna`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Ref2'] = df['Ref2'].mask(df['Ref']!='ABC').fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

Comment: how to update a value for a column based on condition from another column,
Supposing in Pandas we write,

Answer (score 0):

A different way to write this (closer to the `pandas` syntax):

```py
mask = df['Ref']!='ABC'
df.loc[mask,'Ref2'] = np.nan
df['Ref2'] = df['Ref2'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

`dask` closely follows pandas syntax, so often the pandas expression will work.